# Responsive login page won't shrink proportionally

Tags: html, css

im having issues with my login page, so im trying to make the page responsive to the mobile version, but there's some problems:
1.When the page turn to the mobile version, the login box shrinks but the left side of it just goes over the the screen, same goes to the top part of it.
2.The footer won't stick to the bottom of the page.
3.Is there a way to create some space around the login box when it shrinks?
I included a picture of when the page turn to the mobile version, and its the exact appearance i got when i open it from my [LenovoA2010](https://www.gsmarena.com/lenovo_a2010-7507.php) which is 480x854 pixels wide :
[Picture Here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO2e0.png)
Sorry if i wasn't clear enough, this is my first question here and i just started learning Front-End Web Development like about 2 weeks ago, feeling real noob here.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #ebe682;
}

.login-content {
  display: block;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  width: 380px;
  padding: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: whitesmoke;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.avatar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  top: -50px;
  background: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 90%;
}

form>h1 {
  color: #18191a;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

form>h3 {
  color: #18191a;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

form input[type="text"],
form input[type="password"] {
  border: 2px solid #18191a;
  background: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  width: 200px;
  outline: none;
  color: #18191a;
  border-radius: 24px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

form input[type="text"]:focus,
form input[type="password"]:focus {
  width: 280px;
  border-color: #b0b3b8;
}

form input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  background: #18191a;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  outline: none;
  color: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 24px;
  transition: 0.25s;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
}

form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #3a3b3c;
}

a {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #18191a;
}

a:hover {
  color: #3a3b3c;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

footer {
  background: #E4DD56;
  color: #18191a;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #777;
}


/* Mobile Styles */

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  body {
    background-color: #F09A9D;
    /* Red */
  }
}


/* Tablet Styles */

@media only screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 960px) {
  body {
    background-color: #F5CF8E;
    /* Yellow */
  }
}


/* Desktop Styles */

@media only screen and (min-width: 961px) {
  body {
    background-color: #ebe682;
    /* Blue */
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Animated Login Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="login-content">
    <form action="" method="">
      <img class="avatar" src="resources/icons/user-avatar-filled.svg" alt="">
      <h1>Sign In</h1>
      <h3>to continue to Onyi</h3>
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Username">
      <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Password">
      <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">

      <hr>

      <a href="">Forgot password?</a>
    </form>
  </div>

  <footer>
    © 2021 Company, Inc
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you gave the white box a fixed 380px width it will not react to screen change what you can do instead is to use `max-width` with `width` to get what you want

```
.your-form{
    max-width: 380px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

this way you tell your box to expand as much as it wants but never go beyond 380px. this way you get a nice responsive form

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #ebe682;
}

.login-content {
  display: block;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

form {
  max-width: 380px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: whitesmoke;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.avatar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  top: -50px;
  background: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 90%;
}

form>h1 {
  color: #18191a;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

form>h3 {
  color: #18191a;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

form input[type="text"],
form input[type="password"] {
  border: 2px solid #18191a;
  background: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  width: 200px;
  outline: none;
  color: #18191a;
  border-radius: 24px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

form input[type="text"]:focus,
form input[type="password"]:focus {
  width: 280px;
  border-color: #b0b3b8;
}

form input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  background: #18191a;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  outline: none;
  color: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 24px;
  transition: 0.25s;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
}

form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #3a3b3c;
}

a {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #18191a;
}

a:hover {
  color: #3a3b3c;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

footer {
  background: #E4DD56;
  color: #18191a;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #777;
}


/* Mobile Styles */

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  body {
    background-color: #F09A9D;
    /* Red */
  }
}


/* Tablet Styles */

@media only screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 960px) {
  body {
    background-color: #F5CF8E;
    /* Yellow */
  }
}


/* Desktop Styles */

@media only screen and (min-width: 961px) {
  body {
    background-color: #ebe682;
    /* Blue */
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Animated Login Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="login-content">
    <form action="" method="">
      <img class="avatar" src="resources/icons/user-avatar-filled.svg" alt="">
      <h1>Sign In</h1>
      <h3>to continue to Onyi</h3>
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Username">
      <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Password">
      <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">

      <hr>

      <a href="">Forgot password?</a>
    </form>
  </div>

  <footer>
    © 2021 Company, Inc
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but there's another problem, the left, right, and top part of the box is touching the screen, while the bottom part of it touching the footer. So how do i make spaces around it?